# Hangfire job automatically rescheduled after 1 min when using MSMQ with DTC

Tags: c#, msmq, hangfire

I am using Hangfire 1.5.6 with MSMQ and DTC transactions (in order to use remote MSMQ). The problem is that every long running job (> 1 min) is automatically rescheduled after 1 min. This is also done in strange order: job is started again before old job has been canceled.

If I configure Hangfire not to use DTC transactions jobs are running OK.

In the source code I have noticed that MsmqDtcTransaction is opening TransactionScope. Does this scope needs to be open during job execution? What will happen with SQL server transaction log for long running jobs (this particular job is inserting a lot of data into DB)?

I have tried with setting transaction timeout in app.config (this also required changes in machine.config):

```
<system.transactions>
<machineSettings maxTimeout="02:00:00"/>
<defaultSettings timeout="02:00:00" />
</system.transactions>
```

with these changes job was running OK with DTC transactions on.

Is this how Hangfire work with remote MSMQ? Can it be used without transactions?

Comment: "Does TransactionScope needs to be open during job execution?" Depends on whether the MSMQ message should be reinstated in the source queue if the SQL job fails.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? We're having the same issue with remote MSMQs. Long-running job gets retried every minute.

Answer (score 0):

The Hangfire author has checked in a fix for this in 1.6.3: [Hangfire Forums](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/job-automatically-rescheduled-after-1-min-when-using-msmq-with-dtc-tr/2044/4?u=edgars.sults)

From Hangfire source code:

```
public MsmqDtcTransaction()
{
   _scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

and

```
public Message Receive(MessageQueue queue, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var message = queue.Receive(timeout, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
    _suppressedScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, TimeSpan.Zero);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: I have tested version 1.6.5 and there is no more timeout of 1 min, instead there is timeout on 10 minutes, which is windows maximal transaction timeout. Did anyone try running job more than 10 minutes with DTC on?